# Swap two adjacent rows of a column in sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to solve this following problem:

Write a sql query to swap two adjacent rows in a column of a table.

**Input table**

```
Name  Id
 A    1
 B    2
 C    3
 D    4
 E    5
```

**Output table**

```
Name  Id
 A    2
 B    1
 C    4
 D    3
 E    5
```

Description:- 1 is associated with A and 2 with B, swap them, thus now 1 is associated with B and 2 with A, Similarly do for C and D, Since E doesn't has any pair, leave it as it is.

Note:- This may be solved using CASE Statements, but I am trying for a generalized solution, Say currently it is only 5 rows, it may be 10,20 etc..

Eg:

```
SELECT
*,CASE WHEN Name = A then 2 ELSEIF Name = B then 1 etc...
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I'd say keep the id values, swap the names instead. (Easier to code.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use window functions to solve this.

**on MySQL (>= 8.0):**

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(CASE WHEN t.rn % 2 = 0 THEN LAG(Name) OVER (ORDER BY ID) ELSE LEAD(Name) OVER (ORDER BY ID) END, Name) AS Name
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn 
  FROM table_name
) t
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dad3cbe269fdbceafb22a9b29dbe16d)

**on SQL-Server:**

```
SELECT ID, ISNULL(CASE WHEN t.rn % 2 = 0 THEN LAG(Name) OVER (ORDER BY ID) ELSE LEAD(Name) OVER (ORDER BY ID) END, Name) AS Name
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn 
  FROM table_name
) t
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e6ed421d6f3c1ebc61e23a37eb3a852)

Comment: Beat me to it.  My answer withdrawn.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `sql-server`, you can try this.

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10), Id INT)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
 ('A', 1),
 ('B', 2),
 ('C', 3),
 ('D', 4),
 ('E', 5)


;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS RN FROM @YourTable
 )
SELECT T1.Name, ISNULL(T2.Id, T1.Id) Id  FROM CTE T1 
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.RN + CASE WHEN T1.RN%2 = 0 THEN - 1 ELSE 1 END  = T2.RN
```

Result:

```
Name       Id
---------- -----------
A          2
B          1
C          4
D          3
E          5
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but the following is standard ANSI SQL.

You can use a `values()` clause to provide the mapping of the IDs and then join against that:

```
with id_map (source_id, target_id) as ( 
  values
     (1, 2),
     (2, 1) 
)
select t.name, coalesce(m.target_id, t.id) as mapped_id
from the_table t
   left join id_map m on m.source_id = t.id
order by name;
```

Alternatively if you only want to specify the mapping once for one direction, you can use this:

```
with id_map (source_id, target_id) as ( 
  values
     (1, 2) 
)
select t.name,
       case id 
          when m.source_id then m.target_id
          when m.target_id then m.source_id
          else id
       end as mapped_id
from the_table t
   left join id_map m on t.id in (m.source_id, m.target_id)
order by name;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/FBFH52231